# Where can I find a list of the JBOSS deployment statuses for my Server?

Tags: java, jboss

I am creating an application in my JBOSS server that monitors the status of each of the deployments.  I want to return Success if they are all OK and Failure if any of them are Failed.  However, I do not know what statuses can be for a JBOSS deployment.  I cannot seem to find the documentation of an enum online that lists the statuses of deployments.  Where can I find a list of the potential statuses for a JBOSS deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [WildScribe](https://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/13.0/deployment/index.html) which describes the management model.

> The current runtime status of a deployment. Possible status modes are OK, FAILED, and STOPPED. FAILED indicates a dependency is missing or a service could not start. STOPPED indicates that the deployment was not enabled or was manually stopped.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for.